# How to track the previous King was normal jumping or was Capturing jumping in Java

Tags: javascript, java, swing, arraylist, 2d-games

I have designed checkers game by using Java and the King is jumping to any empty spaces along the diagonal line to the left and right, top and down. I can keep track to decide whether the King to move normally or to jump and kill the opponent pieces, the problem is how can I keep records of the previous move was a NORMAL MOVE or was a JUMPING_KILLING MOVE.
I have two boolean function to decide if a normal move or a jump which help me to decide to go for the mandatory JUMPING if there is any.

Here is my jumping boolean function:
public boolean canJumpKing(int player, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2, int r3, int c3) {

```
        if (r3 < 0 || r3 >= 8 || c3 < 0 || c3 >= 8)
            return false;

        if (board[r3][c3] != EMPTY)
            return false;

        for (int i = 1; i < r3 - r1 - 1; i++) {
            if (((r3 > r2) && (c3 > c2)))
                if ((board[r1 + i][c1 + i] != EMPTY) && (board[r1 + i + 1][c1 + i + 1] != EMPTY))
                    return false; }

        for (int i = 1; i < c1 - c3 - 1; i++) {
            if (((r3 < r2) && (c3 < c2)))

                if ((board[r1 - i][c1 - i] != EMPTY) && (board[r1 - i - 1][c1 - i - 1] != EMPTY))
                    return false; }
```

}

Here is my code for adding the mandatory jumping moves to the array_list:

```
            if (board[row][col] == playerKing) {
            if (row<col)
               for (int i=1; i<(7-col); i++) {
                if (canJumpKing(player, row, col, row+i, col+i, row+1+i, col+1+i)) {
                    moves.add(new CheckersMove(row, col, row+1+i, col+1+i));
                        for (int j=1; j<8-(col+1+i); j++){ 
                            if (col+j+i+1<8)
                             if ((board[row+1+j+i][col+j+1+i] != EMPTY))
                                break;
                                if ((board[row+1+j+i][col+j+1+i] == EMPTY)) {
                                    moves.add(new CheckersMove(row, col, row+1+j+i, col+j+1+i));
                        }}}}}
```

The above code extends to several lines to cover all options.
Please help me to keep the track of the previous move if it were a normal move or jumping and killing move.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I kept the the King-jumping and normal piece jumping on the same array, I have decided to separate them on different array_list in such a way that before the King can move it check on the King_Jumping Array if returns null then it moves, in this way I have to decide to check if there was anything on the King_Jumping Array_List of which it returns null if the movement was normal jumping. Thanks anyway for your attempted help if any!